# Listview custom paging with datapager

Tags: asp.net, listview, datapager

Can anyone please tell me how to implement custom paging with datapager. Now I have managed to do this with 2 buttons (for next and previous pages) and LoadListview() method, but I would like to use this method in datapager. Any suggestions?

Code behind file:

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BusinessConnectionString"].ToString());
    SqlDataAdapter adap;
    int startIndex;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            LoadListview();
        }         
    }

    private void LoadListview()
    {
        string FindWhat = Request.QueryString["Find"];
        string FindWhere = Request.QueryString["Where"];
        string TownName = FindWhere;
        string CountyName = FindWhere;
        string PostcodeName = FindWhere;

        //startIndex = int.Parse(ViewState["index"].ToString());
        startIndex = MyDataPager.StartRowIndex * MyDataPager.PageSize;
        int endIndex = startIndex + MyDataPager.PageSize;

        adap = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id_Business) AS MyRow, id_Business, Name, TownName FROM UbeloView WHERE (Name Like '%" + FindWhat + "%' AND TownName Like '%" + TownName + "%') UNION ALL SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id_Business) AS MyRow, id_Business, Name, TownName FROM UbeloView WHERE (Name Like '%" + FindWhat + "%' AND CountyName Like '%" + CountyName + "%') UNION ALL SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id_Business) AS MyRow, id_Business, Name, TownName FROM UbeloView WHERE (Name Like '%" + FindWhat + "%' AND PostcodeName Like '%" + PostcodeName + "%')) AS log WHERE MyRow >=" + startIndex + " AND MyRow <=" + endIndex + " ", conn);

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();


        adap.Fill(ds);

        lstBusiness.DataSource = ds;
        lstBusiness.DataBind();
    }

    protected void MyDataPager_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LoadListview();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This article could help you: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24065/Paging-ListView-With-DataPager

In this article, the author has used a `DataPager_PreRender` to bind his data to a ListView:

```
protected void DataPagerProducts_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ProductList db = new ProductList();
    this.ListViewProducts.DataSource = db.GellAll();
    this.ListViewProducts.DataBind();
}
```

You could try something similar:

```
protected void MyDataPager_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LoadListview();    
}
```

Then all you will need to do is modify your `LoadListview()` method to get the start index from the DataPager control itself.

```
private void LoadListview()
    {
        string FindWhat = Request.QueryString["Find"];
        string FindWhere = Request.QueryString["Where"];
        string TownName = FindWhere;
        string CountyName = FindWhere;
        string PostcodeName = FindWhere;

        startIndex = MyDataPager.StartRowIndex * MyDataPager.PageSize;
        adap = new SqlDataAdapter("<Query removed to save space>", conn);

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();    

        adap.Fill(ds);

        lstBusiness.DataSource = ds;
        lstBusiness.DataBind();
    }
```

As you can see, I am getting the `startIndex` by getting the row index and multiplying it by the page size of your DataPager. Now you can just change this part of your SQL Query from `startIndex * 80` to `startIndex`.

If all goes to plan, you won't need your `btnPrevious` and `btnNext` click events.

I hope this gives you some insight in what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Ill try this in the morning.

Comment: I tried this way, but something is still not working correctly. It shows just a couple of pages in the Datapager (max was 4), and the same amount of pages if i change the pagesize from  80 records per page to 16 or other number.

Comment: @Oak: Can you edit your original post and add the code you are now using?

Comment: Thanks for helping with this problem. I have edited and placed the changes of code. Basically there is everything the same, except the added Prerender event and startindex/endindex. I guess something's wrong with the values.